# In Javascript in a MVC Razor, replace a keyword with a value from the model

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

When you have some JavaScript on an MVC razor view is it possible to do a model variable replacement in the middle of a multipart statement.

To clarify I have the code

```
<script>
 function drawChart() {
    $.post('@Url.Content("~/Home/GetDataAssets")', function (d) {
        ...
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    });
};
```

where I want the type of graph that is displayed to come from the model. So the chart line would have to look something like

```
var chart = new google.visualization.@Model.ChartType(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
```

Where `LineChart` has been replaced by `@Model.ChartType`

This obviously gives the error

> ChartType is being used like a method

Is there a way to make this substitution?

Comment: No, because `@Model.ChartType()` is razor code which is parsed on the server before its sent to the view and `document.getElementById()` is client side code

Comment: You can have something like this - `if('@Model.ChartType' == 'LineChart') { ... var chart = ... } else { ... }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @stephen-muecke said the razor code is parsed on **server side** and the javascript code on **client side**.

If `Model.ChartType` returns a string, i.e. `LineChart`, you only need to output the paranthesis and the content of it `(...)` as text.

To do this you have to add `@{<text> ... </text>}` to output plain text, like below

```
var chart = new google.visualization.@Model.ChartType@{<text>(document.getElementById('chart_div'));</text>}
```

The result of client side will be, with my example

```
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
```